# Some plugins could not be loaded due to unsatisfied dependencies. Fix these issues and restart Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I was working on jenkins and working fine but i don't know what happened Jenkins shows following errors and no jobs are visible to me after that:

I am new in jenkins please help me to solve this.

[image: error logs]

Comment: "You must update Jenkins from version 2.173 to version 2.176 or later to run this plugin."

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins plugins are dependent on Jenkins LTS versions in use. Best way is while installing the Jenkins take latest (but stable) version of plugins.

Since you are using 1.176 version and trying to upgrade the plugins, the latest plugins do not support the older version of Jenkins (since Jenkins follow Parallel incremental development).
You can resolve the problem in 2 ways.

**1. Downgrade the plugins** and keep the LTS Jenkins version as it is. (not preferred solution since you will not be able to use latest functionality of the plugins and using old plugins is not secured).

- Downgrade of plugins will also be suggested by `Manage Jenkins` --> `Manage Plugins` --> `Installed`

**2. Upgrade Jenkins version (LTS 2.24x.x)**

- It is time taking option, but if you are heavely using jenkins for your work it is more suggested to upgrade the version. Besides new plugins have more secured and vast functionalities.
- You can check the [Changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/) and can decided which version is good for you.
- Take a reference of [Upgrading Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.249/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-249-3) link.

To understand plugins and Jenkins LTS version dependency, use Jenkins wiki(Confluence Page).

e.g. [Pipeline:Node and Processes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin) plugin wiki indicates that for version 2.29 you need to have Jenkins version 1.150.1 or higher.

**Note:** Latest Jenkins version supports HTTPS instead of HTTP URL for advanced proxy options under `Manager Jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem it could happened in cause of downgrading jenkins version or updating plugins "Pipeline: Node and Processes".

You need to restore previous jenkins version or downgrade plugin.

Additionally you can configure jenkins to get plugins' versions which fit your jenkins version in "Manage Jenkins" -> "Manage plugins" -> "Advanced" -> "Update site" and set the version you are currently using (for example https://updates.jenkins.io/stable-2.176/update-center.json)